# How can I capture altKey + i, u, e, n with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to set up a keyboard for a foreign language. I'm using jQuery to convert keys pressed into foreign characters. I am using:

- <kbd>A - Z</kbd>
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A - Z</kbd>
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A - Z</kbd>
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A - Z</kbd>

  My code works for all of these except these 4:

  - <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
  - <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
  - <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
  - <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari (I'm using a mac) I get these accent marks - `ˆ`, `¨`, `´`, `˜` - instead of the foreign character that is supposed to go into the textarea.

Here is some of the code:

```
function type(e, char, textArea) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var newPos = start + char.length;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + char + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
    textArea[0].setSelectionRange(newPos, newPos);
}
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
        var textArea = $(this);
        if (e.which == 65 && e.altKey) {type(e, 'अ', textArea);return false;}
        if (e.which == 68 && e.altKey) {type(e, 'ड', textArea);return false;}
        if (e.which == 73 && e.altKey) {type(e, 'इ', textArea);return false;}
        if (e.which == 74 && e.altKey) {type(e, 'ज्ञ', textArea);return false;}
});
```

This works when `e.which` is `65`, `68`, and `74`, but not `73`.
How can I get this to work right?

Comment: FYI, `return false` is the same as `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` together.

Comment: could you do a `console.log` of `e.which` and check what it shows when doing [ALT] + [I] ? Using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2borwez/), it works on chrome for me (Windows 10)

Comment: @Jordumus: On your JSFiddle, I get 18 + 229. Thats the same code I get for [ALT] + [u], [ALT] + [e], & [ALT] + [n].

Comment: I've change it a little bit it works fine in chrome. [here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0fmpgaj/).

Answer (score 1):

You know it's funny, I'm also constantly asking myself why something doesn't work in chrome even though it works just fine everywhere else. In this case, I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that both [e.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) and [e.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) have been depreciated for [e.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [e.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

That being noted, I still use e.keyCode in production, so I know [it still works with the latest version of chrome](https://caniuse.com/?search=KeyboardEvent.keyCode). Maybe do some `console.log(e)` and see what values are actually being returned?

I don't have chrome on my personal computer, so I can't test this, but I simplified your code and made a fiddle that works on my machine. Hopefully it helps point you in the right direction.

```
function InsertSymbol(symbol, $selector) {
  let cursor = $selector[0].selectionStart,
      text = $selector.val();
      
  $selector.val(text.substr(0, cursor) + symbol + text.substr(cursor)).focus()[0].setSelectionRange(++cursor, cursor);
}

$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 69: InsertSymbol('इ', $(this)); break;
      case 73: InsertSymbol('अ', $(this)); break;
      case 78: InsertSymbol('ज्ञ', $(this)); break;
      case 85: InsertSymbol('ड', $(this)); break;
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvgj35kt/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome on Mac and your jsFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/s0fmpgaj/ is working. When I press `ALT + SHIFT + i` 
It returns the special char you defined.